# How to get count number in table with same code?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table 1
Primary key = id

id |kpi_code | result_date | data|

1  |KPI1     | 11/13/2019  | 100 |
2  |KPI1     | 11/14/2019  | 200 |
3  |KPI2     | 11/13/2019  | 50  |
4  |KPI2     | 11/14/2019  | 100 |

Expecting Output:

KPI1 : 300
KPI2 : 150
```

I'm looking for the solution to get the `kpi_code` and calculate the total data of each different `kpi_code`.

Comment: This seems like quite a basic SQL statement, have you tried anything yet?

Comment: your solutions is here : https://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_sum.php

Comment: @CarlBinalla i have updated my comments and sorry for wrong answer :)

Comment: Thank for the help guys, I am not familiar with sql statement do forgive me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `group by` and `sum` should do it:

```
SELECT kpi_code, SUM(data) FROM 1 GROUP BY kpi_code;
```

Comment: What is `1` in `FROM 1`?

Comment: @GMB 1 is the table name

Comment: @GMB In the question it says the table name is "1"

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple `SUM(data)` query, which is grouped by the `kpi_code` column.

```
SELECT kpi_code, SUM(data) AS total
FROM tableName
GROUP BY kpi_code
```

Comment: A downvote does not seem right. Although super-simple, this is the correct solution...